# Is it possible to post a form and at the same time fetch the input data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Suppose i have a form

```
<form action="www.posturl.com" method="post" >    
    <input type="text" name="test" />    
    <input type="submit" />    
</form>
```

Is there someway I can fetch the input field 'test' using javascript at the time of posting the form?If yes,is there a way I could prevent it and only able to POST to that action url only?

Comment: you can call form submit event and get values of form using jquery/js

Comment: @RakeshSharma Is there someway I could prevent someone from getting a form data,and only post to the action url?

Comment: Why? Why do you want that? Forms post only to the action url

Comment: how can someone get data? i don't understand your mean please be clear

Comment: No this is regarding my clients.I dont want my client to get CVV of a credit card using submit action,they should just post it to the url i given.Im giving them a javascript which they should use in their page,then only they can use my service.But I dont want my clients to store the CVV of credit card,rather post it to my URL

Comment: you can use a unique string match or ip restriction for this for allow service call from this ip and other ips blocked. or try to send any unique string with callind and match if it exists then output that else ignore or there are many other way for restrict web service call

Comment: See,Im not asking about the access to webservice.They can access my webservice only if their IP matches.But my question is is there someway I can prevent them from fetching a form field somehow while they post to my form action URL?

Comment: not clear please be more specific what you want to do and what you have for this

Answer (score 0):

Someone could grab the data using JavaScript. The following example uses jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('form').on('submit', function() {
            var test = $(this).find('[name="test"]').val(); // grab value of the input named 'test'
            // do something with the data
        });
    });
</script>
```

If someone has control over the contents of the page where the form resides, there is no way to prevent this.

You could provide the form to your clients as an iFrame showing a page from a different domain. Then, *Same Origin Policy* will prevent them from accessing the form via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can post the form using `AJAX` -

```
<form action="www.posturl.com" method="post" >
    <input name="test" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("form").on(submit,function(){
        var form = $(this);
        var action = form.attr('action');
        var data = form.serialize();

        $.post(action,data)
        .done(function(response){
            if(response.success == TRUE)
            {
               // If successfully submitted
            }
            else
            {
               // If not
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know for sure why you want to do this,

but you can try this-

You can remove an existing event using jQuery's unbind function, eg:

```
if(user == 'admin')
{
    $('#myForm').unbind('submit');

//will remove all onsubmit events from #myForm. Then you can add a new event using normal jQuery:

`$('#myForm').submit(function(e)` { /* your logic here */ });

}
```

so, you can provide the logic that if the user is you, (and not your clients), then this unbinds the existing submit event, adds a new submit event with your javascript function while your clients would only be working with the previous submit event which does not have the javascript function which fetches the input filed